# Destructor doesn't print line on console

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

I'm using visual studio 2013 and printing some cout commands to test, When i debug my code, the control go inside the destructor of both class but it's not printing cout statement on console.

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

class Uni
{
 public:
 ~Uni()
 {
    cout << "I am in Uni Destructor" << endl;
 }

 Uni()
 {
    cout << "I am in Uni Constructor" << endl;
 }

};


class Student: public Uni
{
 public:

 Student()
 {
    cout << "I am in Student Constructor" << endl;
 }
 ~Student()
 {
    cout << "I am in Student Destructor" << endl;
 }



};

int main()
{
  Student s;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

I am in Uni Constructor

I am in Student Constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you get the output at this point, i.e. after the `pause`.

```
int main()
{
  Student s;
  system("pause");

  // here; but s is not destroyed yet
  return 0;
}
```

But at that point `s` is still not destroyed. It will be destroyed when get out of the scope where it's declared, i.e. when get out of the function `main`.

You can put `s` into further scope for testing.

```
int main()
{
  {
    Student s;
  } // s will be destroyed here

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In which objects are created heap or stack?

Comment: we delete something if it is created in heap?

Comment: @kappo Sorry I didn't get what you mean. You meant using `delete` when using `new` to create objects?

Comment: @kappo Yes, if you create the object like `Student* ps = new Student;` then you have to destroy it explicitly like `delete ps;`. At this point the object is destroyed and the destructor would be invoked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159325/discussion-between-kappo-and-songyuanyao).

Answer (score 0):

Your Code looks fine, cout ist a buffered console output stream object instance: are you sure that your destructor message ist not just buffered to be written after the last closing brace and flush of cout?